# For every father of only a leaf node, remove the leaf and add its value with the father

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree

If I find a father with only a leaf as a child I have to remove the leaf and add its value with the father

This is my solution but I have a problem when I try to remove the leaf

```
bool isLeaf(tree a){ //function to verify if the node is a leaf

if(a->left==NULL && a->right==NULL)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}


void removeLeaves(tree* a){

if(*a == NULL) return;

//verify if the node has only a child
 if(((*a)->left==NULL&&(*a)->right!=NULL) || ((*a)->right==NULL&&(*a)->left!=NULL)){

    if((*a)->right==NULL){ //if has only left child,verify  if it is a leaf
        if(isLeaf((*a)->left)){
            (*a)->info = (*a)->info + (*a)->left->info; 
            free((*a)->left);



        }
    }
    if((*a)->left==NULL){ //if has only right child,verify  if it is a leaf
        if(isLeaf((*a)->right)){
            (*a)->info = (*a)->info + (*a)->right->info; 
            free((*a)->right);

        }
    }
}


removeLeaves(&((*a)->left));
removeLeaves(&((*a)->right));
}
```

Minimal:

```
if((*a)->right==NULL){ //if has only left child,verify  if it is a leaf
        if(isLeaf((*a)->left)){
            (*a)->info = (*a)->info + (*a)->left->info; 
            free((*a)->left);
```

If I reach this point (there's only a child to the left and it is a leaf), I sum its value with the father and then free it. without the free I obtain the sum but with the free I get segmentation fault. Same thing with only a child to the right.

Edit1:
I changed the condition to:

```
if(((*a)->right==NULL&&(*a)->left!=NULL) && isLeaf((*a)->left)){


        (*a)->info = (*a)->info + (*a)->left->info; 

        free((*a)->left);
        (*a)->left = NULL;  

}
```

And this works but I don't understand why.

Edit2:(implementation with struct)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>


typedef int InfoTree;

typedef struct StructTree {
  InfoTree info;
  struct StructTree* right;
  struct StructTree* left;
} NodeTree;

typedef NodeTree* Tree;

//functions
Tree createTree(InfoTree infoRoot,Tree left,Tree right);
Tree emptyTree();
void print_tree(Tree a);
bool isLeaf(Tree a);
void removeLeaves(Tree* a);

int main(){

    /* Binary Tree:                */
    /*          3               */
    /*       /     \           */
    /*      7       5          */
    /*    /   \      \         */
    /*   4    2       9        */
    /*       /                     */
    /*      6                      */

    Tree A = createTree( 6  , emptyTree(), emptyTree() ) ;
    Tree B = createTree( 2 , emptyTree(), emptyTree() ) ;
    Tree C = createTree( 9 , emptyTree(), emptyTree() ) ;

    Tree D = createTree( 5 , emptyTree(), C);
    Tree E = createTree( 4  , A, emptyTree());

    Tree F = createTree( 7 , E, B);

    Tree H = createTree( 3  , F, D);
    Tree t = H;
    print_tree(t);
    removeLeaves(&t);
    printf("\n");
    print_tree(t);
    return 0;



}

Tree createTree(InfoTree infoRoot,
              Tree left,
              Tree right) {
  Tree a = (Tree) malloc(sizeof(Tree));
  a->info = infoRoot;
  a->left = left;
  a->right = right;
  return a;
}

Tree emptyTree() {
  return NULL;
}


void print_tree(Tree a) {
    if (a==NULL) {
        printf("()");
    }
    else {
        printf("( %d ",a->info);
        print_tree(a->left);
        printf(" ");
        print_tree(a->right);
        printf(" )");
    }
}

bool isLeaf(Tree a){ //function to verify if the node is a leaf

if(a->left==NULL && a->right==NULL)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}


void removeLeaves(Tree* a){

if(*a == NULL) return;

//verify if the node has only a child
 if(((*a)->left==NULL&&(*a)->right!=NULL) || ((*a)->right==NULL&&(*a)->left!=NULL)){

    if((*a)->right==NULL){ //if has only left child,verify  if it is a leaf
        if(isLeaf((*a)->left)){
            (*a)->info = (*a)->info + (*a)->left->info; 
            free((*a)->left);
        (*a)->left = NULL;



        }
    }
    if((*a)->left==NULL){ //if has only right child,verify  if it is a leaf
        if(isLeaf((*a)->right)){
            (*a)->info = (*a)->info + (*a)->right->info; 
            free((*a)->right);
            (*a)->right = NULL;

        }
    }
}


removeLeaves(&((*a)->left));
removeLeaves(&((*a)->right));
}
```

This is the original source code with the tree structure and the functions to work on the tree. If I modify it with the above conditions (first Edit1) it works but I don't understand why.
Thank you

Comment: "I have a problem" is not specific enough. Are you getting errors? Does the program not do what you want it to do? Please provide the exact error message and/or describe how _exactly_ your program behaves and how it's supposed to behave.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It returns me segmentation fault

Comment: This is what this function have to return https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sLG7TbbHsXkzff14_EBiXhW3lgkjI3WM/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I don't see any reason for `removeLeaves` taking in a pointer to a tree...

Comment: Also, [mcve] please.

Comment: The function's structure was written by the teacher and I have to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After freeing the leaf you need to set its entry in the father to null.

Your function is recursive. If it finds a single leaf its memory is freed, but at the end of the function it tries to access that memory. This is known as "dangling pointer."

*Edit:*

There is another issue, here shown at your initial source:

```
if((*a)->right==NULL){
    if(isLeaf((*a)->left)){
        // ... irrelevant lines removed ...
        (*a)->left = NULL;
    }
}
if((*a)->left==NULL){ // <== see text below
    if(isLeaf((*a)->right)){ // BOOM!
```

If a leaf is found in the first part then the `right` pointer is NULL. After setting the `left` pointer to NULL the marked `if` evaluates to `true`, and `isLeaf()` is called with a NULL pointer giving you the segmentation fault.

Comment: so, after freeing I should add  (*a)->right = NULL; ?

Comment: same problem (segmentation fault)

Comment: Please read the text linked by @Antti and give us a **complete** source that can be compiled and run. Especially the struct definition of `tree` and the example tree as well as the calling code is important to help us help you.

Comment: Ok sorry, I posted the code with the struct definition.

Comment: thanks man, you're right! I have to change the second condition with an else, now I understand.

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck in eliminating all other quirks... ;-)